# SteelBrick - Generate Document in Word(doc) Format

Tags: document, cpq, steelbrick

In SteelBrick CPQ, is it possible to generate the document in docx format? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi Saumya, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly what you've tried and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hii Saumya if you want to generate the document in docx format then i thnk import the data and then converted it into docx format here is the link which maybe helpful for you[This will provide you to basic step of importing the data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK4uj9_YHX4)